# Returning items from classes in a list

Tags: python, class

I want to return all values from my custom class that are stored in a list similar to what can be done with node.items() in networkx :

```
class CustomClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.idx = 1
        self.value = 5

class_list = [c1, c2, c3, c4]

clas_values = class_list.values()

class_values -> [(idx_c1, value_c1), (idx_c2, value_c2), .....]
```

What I think I need to do is to use the decorator *@classmethod* and write a function `values()` in my `CustomClass()`?

I'm not looking for a list comprehension since I would have to copy-paste this multiple times.

Comment: `[(c.idx, c.value) for c in class_list]`

Comment: This works, but I thought its kinda obvious that I want an easy callable function for this purpose and not always rewrite what you are suggesting.

Comment: Phil, but if you put the code Olvin sent in a function, dont you get an easily callable function?

Comment: Well, let's say it was just early in the morning and I got stuck on the idea that I want to call class.values(). values(class) would do the same trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use your proposed syntax you will have to write your own collection, here is an example:

```py
class CustomClass:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.idx = i
        self.value = 5

class CustomList(list):
    def values(self):
        return [(c.idx, c.value) for c in self]

class_list = CustomList([CustomClass(3), CustomClass(4)])

clas_values = class_list.values()
print(clas_values)
```

prints
`[(3, 5), (4, 5)]`

Otherwise, as already suggested, you could simply use a helper function, for example:

```py
def values(lst):
    return [(c.idx, c.value) for c in lst]
```